# When SSHing into system, is there a way to launch netbeans from command-line like I do VIM?

Tags: linux, bash, netbeans

VIM seems integrated to the terminal. Can I open a remote file from the command-line with netbeans? Does it have shell integration? Any further explanation on this so I can better conceptually understand it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few options:

1. Using ssh -X to forward X. Then you
   can start netbeans remotely.
2. Use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) so you mount the
   remote filesystem locally over ssh.
   You can use then local copy of
   netbeans to work on remote files.
3. Using rsync to have a local copy
4. The best one - use version control

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, providing certain conditions are met!

Using ssh, you can tunnel the display of X-Window applications, meaning you can run the application (the X-Client) on one machine, and have it display on another (the X-Server).

You'll need to launch ssh with the -X option (or -Y, but preferably -X) to allow tunnelling, and then run NetBeans from the commandline as usual:

```
netbeans MyFile.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about [X-forwarding](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html). The link points to a very verbose and detailed howto/tutorial.